# Postgres convert date time difference into HH:MM:SS

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

Ex:

```
startTime-EndTime
```

Diff is 0 years 0 months 5 days 20 hours 6 minutes 30 seconds. I want to convert this into HH:MM:SS format : 120:06:30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Duration                                                 // Represent a span-of-time in terms of total number of whole seconds plus a fractional second in nanos.
.between(                                                // Calculate elapsed time.
    myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ,  // Start
    myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ,  // Stop
)                                                        // Returns a `Duration` object.
.toString()                                              // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format of `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`.
```

## java.time

Doing it on the Java side is simple with a column of a data type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later (for support of the modern *java.time* classes).

### `OffsetDateTime`

Retrieve your moments as [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) objects, per [JDBC 4.2 spec](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221).

```
OffsetDateTime start = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
OffsetDateTime stop = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

### `Duration`

Calculate elapsed time as a `Duration` object.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;
```

### ISO 8601

Generate a standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string of the format [`PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) where the `P` marks the beginning (probably stands for “period” – no standardized terms in date-time handling unfortunately), and the `T` separates years-months-days from hours-minutes-seconds. So an hour and a half would be `PT1H30M`. Your example of `5 days 20hours 6minutes 30 seconds` would be `P5DT20H6M30S`.

The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 format by default. So you generate text by simply calling `toString`. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```

> P5DT20H6M30S

To parse, call `parse`.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "P5DT20H6M30S" ) ;
```

Note that `Duration` counts days as 24-hour chunks of time, without regard for the calendar. If you want calendar-based dates, use [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html) class. If you want both concepts together, use [`PeriodDuration`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html) class from the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/), but think twice as mixing the two concepts is usually unwise and impractical.

I strongly advise you *not* represent a span-of-time using the clock notation as shown in your Question. Doing so is ambiguous, error-prone with people misinterpreting the text, as I have personally seen happen in business scenarios. The standard format is much wiser.

### `Duration::to…Part`

But if you insist on the clock-formatting, create a string by calling the `to…Part` methods on `Duration`.

```
String output = d.toDaysPart() + ":" + d.toHoursPart() + ":" + d.toMinutesPart() + ":" + d.toSecondsPart() + "." + d.toNanosPart() ;
```

#### `toHours` versus `toHoursPart`

If want all the days reported as hours, get total number of hours across entire span-of-time by calling [`toHours`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toHours()) rather than [`toHoursPart`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toDaysPart()). Then get the parts of minutes and seconds.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;
String output = d.toHours() + ":" + d.toMinutesPart() + ":" + d.toSecondsPart() ;
```

> 120:06:30

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using postgresql.

To compute the difference between two timestamps as a number of seconds, use :

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (startTime - endTime))
```

Then you tun this value back to a timestamp with function TO_TIMESTAMP, and format this as a time using function TO_CHAR.

The hour part is tricky as you want to display values greater than 24 (which, as you would expect, is the maximum allowed in postgres): you need to use a little arithmetics to compute it.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (startTime - endTime))/60/60,
    ':',
    TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(
         EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (startTime - endTime))
      ), 'MI:SS')
 )
FROM my_table
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21798912)

Comment: @NikolaYovchev I guess my post was edited while you were posting your comment